# Can android access a PostgreSQL database from a traditional web application?

Tags: android, sql, database

I am fairly new to databases, and StackOverflow(so bare with my question). My friends and I are trying to create a "student" version android app of a current school website. We just want to create something that is mobile friendly and easy to use for the students. However, the current website is a traditional web application (not REST API + SPA) and uses PostgreSQL as its database. I am wondering if we can connect a mobile app to that database to access the student's data or if we have to create a separate database.

Comment: If you are concerned with the quality of your question, you might want to take a look at the [SO Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). These two documents will help others answer your question quicker. And I wish you luck in finding your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same database but you need to create a backend service (REST API o Web Service) to comunicate the device and the database. You can use technologies like **Nodejs**, **Go**.

Hope this help you